# Feeding image data in tensorflow for transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow for transfer learning. I downloaded the pre-trained model inception3 from the tutorial. In the code, for prediction:

```
prediction = sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'}:image_data})
```

Is there a way to feed the png image. I tried changing `DecodeJpeg` to `DecodePng` but it did not work. Beside, what should I change if I want to feed decoded image file like a numpy array or a batch of arrays?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try passing PNG image to this operation? Documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/decode-jpeg) is saying that this operation supports decoding PNGs also.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The shipped InceptionV3 graph used in [`classify_image.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) only supports JPEG images out-of-the-box. There are two ways you could use this graph with PNG images:

1. Convert the PNG image to a `height` x `width` x 3 (channels) Numpy array, for example using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), then feed the `'DecodeJpeg:0'` tensor:

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   from PIL import Image
   # ...

   image = Image.open("example.png")
   image_array = np.array(image)[:, :, 0:3]  # Select RGB channels only.

   prediction = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})
   ```

   Perhaps confusingly, `'DecodeJpeg:0'` is the *output* of the `DecodeJpeg` op, so by feeding this tensor, you are able to feed raw image data.
2. Add a `tf.image.decode_png()` op to the imported graph. Simply switching the name of the fed tensor from `'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'` to `'DecodePng/contents:0'` does not work because there is no `'DecodePng'` op in the shipped graph. You can add such a node to the graph by using the `input_map` argument to [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#import_graph_def):

   ```py
   png_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
   decoded_png = tf.image.decode_png(png_data, channels=3)
   # ...

   graph_def = ...
   softmax_tensor = tf.import_graph_def(
       graph_def,
       input_map={'DecodeJpeg:0': decoded_png},
       return_elements=['softmax:0'])

   sess.run(softmax_tensor, {png_data: ...})
   ```

Comment: I tried with your first method. It outputs 'Unable to get element from the feed.' I am not sure why. But your second one work. Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm, the "Unable to get element from the feed" error is strange - it implies that `image_array` is being treated as an array of strings, so there might be something missing in the type conversion of your image to a TensorFlow tensor.

Comment: From your second answer, I assumes that 'DecodeJpeg:0' is constructed with  `jpg_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[]);
decoded_jpg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpg_data, channels=3)
` So it waits for a string instead of  a numpy array.

Comment: Is it possible to feed it a numpy array directly? For example, if an image was already decoded.

Comment: @Yamaneko: Option 1 shows how to feed a numpy array directly. (The tensor `DecodeJpeg:0` is the output of an op that decodes a JPEG image, so if you feed a replacement value, it should also be a decoded image.)

Comment: Additionally for opition 1, is it possible to pass and image_array of shape [batch_size, img_shape, img_shape, channels] ?

Comment: @viggie That depends on the graph structure downstream from the `tf.decode_jpeg()` op. I expect that there's a `tf.reshape()` to add a batch dimension soon afterwards; if you fed the output of that op, you could pass in a batch of images that way.

Comment: Do you know if this is valid anymore? I wanted to achieve your solution 1, and was unsuccessful in feeding decoded images. I read an image with opencv and convert to string, which raises a "not a valid jpeg" error. DecodeJpeg node however accepts a jpeg-encoded image as a string.

Comment: @milez These ops still work the same way, so the answer is still valid. I suspect there is a problem with your OpenCV conversion to string, but there's not enough room here to go into detail. Feel free to post a new question with a minimal example of what you've tried!

Comment: Okay I figured it out. The first node in pretrained Inception v3, according to the tf example, is `DecodeJpeg/contents:0`, which requires a jpeg encoded image as string. The second node, however, is `DecodeJpeg:0`, which accepts a decoded image as numpy array, like you said. I simply missed the fact that `/contents` was not included in your example :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should handle of both cases.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image_file = 'test.jpeg'
with tf.Session() as sess:

    #     softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    if image_file.lower().endswith('.jpeg'):
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_file, 'rb').read()
        prediction = sess.run('final_result:0', {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    elif image_file.lower().endswith('.png'):
        image = Image.open(image_file)
        image_array = np.array(image)[:, :, 0:3]
        prediction = sess.run('final_result:0', {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})

    prediction = prediction[0]    
    print(prediction)
```

or shorter version with direct strings:

```py
image_file = 'test.png' # or 'test.jpeg'
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_file, 'rb').read()
ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])

with tf.Session() as sess:        
    predictions = sess.run(output_layer_name, {ph: image_data} )
```