# Feeding both jpeg and png images to the pre-trained inception3 model?

Tags: tensorflow

I gather from this question and its answer [ [feeding image data in tensorflow for transfer learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484148/feeding-image-data-in-tensorflow-for-transfer-learning) ] that adding a new op to the imported graph will help, but it isn't clear to me if the resulting graph will handle both png and jpeg inputs automatically, and at the same time.

The answer to the above question suggests the following:

```
png_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
decoded_png = tf.image.decode_png(png_data, channels=3)
# ...

graph_def = ... 
softmax_tensor = tf.import_graph_def(
    graph_def,
    input_map={'DecodeJpeg:0': decoded_png},
    return_elements=['softmax:0'])

sess.run(softmax_tensor, {png_data: ...})
```

Does this mean that a PNG input must be passed in as

```
sess.run(softmax_tensor, {png_data: image_array})
```

And a JPEG input must be given to the graph as

sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})

Would the second statement work after the graph has been modified and an op added at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers in the previous question center around switching the graph from taking JPEGs to PNGs.  With the network as specified, there's no way for it to handle both.

You have a few options if you need to deal with both types.

1. Handle the decoding yourself, either with PIL, or TensorFlow, and feed the decoded image bytes into the graph at the output of the existing decode node.
2. If you're happy feeding the network, then do a two-step operation where you re-plumb the input to read from a variable, and create two new nodes that write decoded output to that variable.

   sess.run(feed_jpeg, feed_dict={in_jpg: my_jpg}) 
   sess.run(the_network)

or

```
sess.run(feed_png, feed_dict={in_png: my_png})
sess.run(the_network)
```

3. Create a more complex conditional input path where you can feed a flag value that tells it what data type it is, and uses TF conditionals to only pull on the specified decode node.
4. [Write a new op](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) that dispatches to either decode_png or decode_jpeg as necessary, based upon the format string at the start of the data.

I'm hoping we'll expose some string comparison ops so that you could write (4) in pure TensorFlow, but I don't have a timeline for any of that.

Comment: Thanks! Any pointers to documentation on how I can do the 4th (an op that dispatches to either decode_png or decode_jpeg)?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't parse your last sentence well. That answers my follow-up question. Thank you.

Comment: I've linked it to the write a new op docs for clarity for later readers - thanks for mentioning it. :)