# How to retrain inception-v1 model?

Tags: tensorflow

I have successfully gone through the [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html), which explains how to retrain inception-v3 model and later successfully retrained the same model o train the model for specific purposes.

The model, however, is complex and slow compared to other, simpler models, such as inception-v1 which accuracy is good enough for some tasks. Specifically, I would like to retrain the model to use it on Android and ideally the performance in terms of speed should be comparable to original [TensorFlow Android demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android). Anyway, I tried to retrain the inception-v1 model from [this link](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip) with following modifications in retrain.py:

```
BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME = 'avgpool0/reshape:0'
BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE = 2048
MODEL_INPUT_WIDTH = 224
MODEL_INPUT_HEIGHT = 224
MODEL_INPUT_DEPTH = 3
JPEG_DATA_TENSOR_NAME = 'input'
RESIZED_INPUT_TENSOR_NAME = 'input'
```

As opposed to inception v3, inception v1 does not have any decodeJpeg or resize nodes:

inception v3 nodes:

```
DecodeJpeg/contents
DecodeJpeg
Cast
ExpandDims/dim
ExpandDims
ResizeBilinear/size
ResizeBilinear
...
pool_3
pool_3/_reshape/shape
pool_3/_reshape
softmax/weights
softmax/biases
softmax/logits/MatMul
softmax/logits
softmax
```

inception v1 nodes:

```
input
conv2d0_w
conv2d0_b
conv2d1_w
conv2d1_b
conv2d2_w
conv2d2_b
...
softmax1_pre_activation
softmax1
avgpool0/reshape/shape
avgpool0/reshape
softmax2_pre_activation/matmul
softmax2_pre_activation
softmax2
output
output1
output2
```

so I guess the images have to be reshaped before being fed into the graph.

Right now the error occurs when hitting the following function:

```
def run_bottleneck_on_image(sess, image_data, image_data_tensor,
                            bottleneck_tensor):
  """Runs inference on an image to extract the 'bottleneck' summary layer.

  Args:
    sess: Current active TensorFlow Session.
    image_data: Numpy array of image data.
    image_data_tensor: Input data layer in the graph.
    bottleneck_tensor: Layer before the final softmax.

  Returns:
    Numpy array of bottleneck values.
  """

  bottleneck_values = sess.run(
      bottleneck_tensor,
      {image_data_tensor: image_data})
  bottleneck_values = np.squeeze(bottleneck_values)
  return bottleneck_values
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a
>   Operation into a Tensor.

I guess the data on input node of inception v1 graph has to be reshaped to match the data after passing the following nodes in inception v3:

```
DecodeJpeg/contents
DecodeJpeg
Cast
ExpandDims/dim
ExpandDims
ResizeBilinear/size
ResizeBilinear
```

If anyone has already managed to retrain the inception v1 model or has an idea how to reshape the data in inception v1 case to match inception v3, I would be very thankful for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to solve the same problem right now. Have you come to a solution?

Comment: Did you manage to create a retrain script for v1? If so please could you share as the answer below doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have solved this or not but I am working on a similar problem.

I am trying to use a different model (not Inception-v1 or Inception-v3) with the Inception-v3 transfer learning tutorial. This post seems to be on the right track of remapping the input of the new model (in your case inception-v1) to play nice with the jpeg encoding used in the rest of the tutorial: 
[feeding image data in tensorflow for transfer learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484148/feeding-image-data-in-tensorflow-for-transfer-learning)

The only problem I am having is a error in my input saying "Cannot convert a tensor of type uint8 to an input type of float32" but this may at least put you on the right track.

Good Luck!

Comment: You probably figured that out by now, but the error sounds like you have to convert images from the [0, 255] interval to [0, 1] or, more likely, [-0.5, 0.5].

Answer (score 0):

(For the ones who are still interested) 
Bottleneck tensor size should be 1024 for inception-v1. For me, the following setup works with mentioned [inception-v1](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip) for [this retrain script](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/examples/image_retraining). No need for jpeg data tensor or else.

```
bottleneck_tensor_name = 'avgpool0/reshape:0'
bottleneck_tensor_size = 1024
input_width = 224
input_height = 224
input_depth = 3
resized_input_tensor_name = 'input:0'
```

Comment: The retrain script link doesn't work anymore please can you add a new one.

Comment: the following link should work: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/examples/image_retraining