# Tensorflow: open a PIL.Image?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I have a script that obscures part of an image and runs it through a prediction net to see which parts of the image most strongly influence the tag prediction. To do this, I open a local image with PIL and resize it, along with adding a black box at various intervals. I use Tensorflow to open my model and I want to pass the image to the model, but it's not expecting a value with this specific shape:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "obscureImage.py", line 55, in <module>
    originalPrediction, originalTag = predict(originalImage, labels)
  File "obscureImage.py", line 23, in predict
    {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 943, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0', which has shape '()'
```

This is my code:

```
def predict(image, labels):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read() # What I used to use.

        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                               {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})
        predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

        top_k = predictions.argsort()[-5:][::-1]  # Getting top 5 predictions

        return predictions[0], labels[top_k[0]] # Return the raw value of tag matching and the matching tag.

originalImage = Image.open(args.input).resize((args.imgsz,args.imgsz)).convert('RGB')
originalPrediction, originalTag = predict(originalImage, labels)
```

Opening and using the image from the disk works fine, but of course then it's not my modified image. I tried using `tf.image.decode_jpeg(image,0)` as the parameter for the softmax tensor, but that gives me `TypeError: Expected string passed to parameter 'contents' of op 'DecodeJpeg', got <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=224x224 at 0x2592F883358> of type 'Image' instead.`

Answer (score 13):

Use the `img_to_array` function from Keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from PIL import Image
    
pil_img = Image.new(3, (200, 200))
image_array  = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(pil_img)
```

Comment: tf.keras.preprocessing is now deprecated. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing. However tf.keras.utils.img_to_array can be used.

Answer (score 3):

The 'DecodeJpeg:0/contents:0' is an operation that is meant to  decode a base64 string to raw image data. 
You are trying to feed in the raw image data. 
So you should feed it into the 'DecodeJpeg:0' wich is the output of the  'DecodeJpeg:0/contents:0' or to into the 'Mul:0' that is the input of the graph.
Don't forget to resize as the input should be of shape (299,299,3)
The Mul takes in a (1,299,299,3)

Try it like this:

```
image = Image.open("example.jepg")
image.resize((299,299), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image_array = np.array(image)[:, :, 0:3]  # Select RGB channels only.

prediction = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg:0': image_array})
or
prediction = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Mul:0': [image_array]})
```

[as well discussed in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34497833/5015616)

To visualize the operations:

```
 for i in sess.graph.get_operations():
            print (i.values())
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Maximilian's answers didn't work, but here's what did work for me:

```
from io import BytesIO

def predict(image, labels, sess):
    imageBuf = BytesIO()
    image.save(imageBuf, format="JPEG")
    image = imageBuf.getvalue()

    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image})
    predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-5:][::-1]  # Getting top 5 predictions

    return predictions[top_k[0]], labels[top_k[0]] # Return the raw value of tag matching and the matching tag.
```

Made a byte buffer, saved the PIL Image into it, got its value and passed it in. I'm still new to Tensorflow and image processing, so if anyone has a concrete reason why this worked and Max's stuff didn't, it would make a good addendum to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL's  [`getdata()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.getdata)

> Returns the contents of an image as a sequence object containing pixel
>   values. The sequence object is flattened, so that values for line one
>   follow directly after the values of line zero, and so on.

or Tensorflow's [`gfile`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py).

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_filename, 'rb').read()
```

Comment: Afraid neither of those work. Passing in `image.getdata()` as the parameter to `sess.run` gave me: `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50176, 3) for Tensor 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0', which has shape '()'`. Trying to do `image = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()` gave me `TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=224x224 at 0x28C3F772898>`. Seems a bit odd to me that it expects something of shape ()...

Comment: @IronWaffleMan: FastGFile expects a string with the filename, not the image itself. I updated the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I know it does, but I'm not passing it a filename. I'm passing it an image I've modified with PIL.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, and works good with me. Feel free to change parameters to adjust your solution. The image is the PIL image as a input.

```
def read_tensor_from_image(image, input_height=224, input_width=224,
            input_mean=0, input_std=255):

  float_caster = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])
  sess = tf.Session()
  result = sess.run(normalized)

  return result
```