# Tensorflow Inception V3 Training Error

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a tumor image classifier by retraining Inception V3 on Docker. When I run the Python script, the images in my class subfolders are not detected. All images are in png format. This is the code and error:

```
root@c47d0d562199:/classifier# python retrain.py 
bottlenecks_dir=bottlenecks --how_many_steps=4000 
--model_dir=inception          
--summaries_dir=training_summaries/long 
--output_graph=retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=retrained_labels.txt     
--image_dir=Images       

2017-11-16 21:26:20.099812: W  
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-16 21:26:20.099898: W    
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-16 21:26:20.099912: W   
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

Looking for images in 'Bening_Phyllodes_Tumor'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Benign_Tubular_Adenoma'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Malignant_Ductal_Carcinoma'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Malignant_Lobular_Carcinoma'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Malignant_Papillary_Carcinoma'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Bening_Fibroadenoma'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Malignant_Mucinous_Carcinoma'
No files found
Looking for images in 'Bening_Adenosis'
No files found
No valid folders of images found at Images
```

It seems like there is some issue with the image formatting since the subfolders are detectable and have been read. Does Inception V3 only read .jpg? My images are in png format.

Comment: How many images are there? Can you just convert them to jpg?

Comment: you seem to be missing `--` before `bottlenecks_dir`, btw

Comment: I have about 10 K images so thats going to be an ordeal. Is there a way I can convert all of them to jpg at once?

Comment: Pardon the missing —. It must be there since the bottleneck directory has been created.

Comment: It seems that `retrain.py` (assuming you're using [this one on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) only handles jpg images. You can probably  edit the script to look for png images as well, and change `tf.image.decode_jpeg` to `tf.image.decode_png`. The cleaner approach would be to write a new script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feeding image data in tensorflow for transfer learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484148/feeding-image-data-in-tensorflow-for-transfer-learning)